# Unable to Successfully Build Go-Based Docker Image

Tags: docker, go

When attempting to build a GoLang-based Docker Image, the Docker executor runs into the following error:

> . . .go: $GIT_REPO@v1.9.11: reading $GIT_REPO/go.mod at revision v0.0.07: unknown revision v0.0.07

at the following `RUN` instruction from the `Dockerfile` used:

```
RUN go build . . .
```

where `GIT_REPO` represents the private repo. full path, including owner and name.

The Docker executor encounters this error with `go1.13.x` and higher; the Docker executor does **not** encounter this error with `go1.12.x`.

The vendor dir. contains *all* required packages.  Tags are confirmed to be present.

Proper SSH keys were even added to the private Go common repo. with successful

```sh
git clone . . .
```

commands outside of `build`ing Docker images, but still encountering the same error above.

Comment: Could you paste the result of `go env`? Do you use the go module? Is the project inside the GOPATH?

Comment: Never check in keys/secrets into a git repo - even if it is a private repo. Doing so will not fix your Docker build failure (the repo is private and thus the docker build cannot get the keys anyway). See answer below on how to Docker build from a private repo.

Comment: I'm having this same issue with on-premises bitbucket as well and Go 1.15.3.. I can't figure out what the build container is missing. Revision is found just fine otherwise, only fails inside the build container. Did anyone find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

### ***EDIT:***

Verify your remote repo in [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/) actually has the `v0.0.7` tag you're trying to build against.

While a local build may work if the git tag exists locally - a docker build will pull from the remote source and fail with an error like `go.mod at revision v0.0.7: unknown revision v0.0.7` - if the tag does not exist *remotely*.

[image]

To push your local tags to the remote repo:

```
git push --tags
```

For more granular tag operations [see](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging).

---

Docker builds by default can only access public repos. Since you need access to a private repo, you need to include a read-ssh key to the *Docker* build process (keys should never be checked into the repo!).

It is ***critically important***, however, you do this in a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), so you do not include your SSH keys in the final image.

This [blog post](https://vsupalov.com/build-docker-image-clone-private-repo-ssh-key/) walks through all the steps. But to include a working example:

To build the docker image:

```
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" \
    docker build -t "myapp:v0.0.1" --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY .
```

And the `Dockerfile` using a `bitbucket.org` private repo site:

```
FROM golang:1.14.6 AS build
  
WORKDIR /bld
COPY *.go go.mod go.sum ./

ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
# ***NEVER*** DO THIS IN A SINGLE-STAGE DOCKER BUILD (see below)
RUN \
        mkdir -p ~/.ssh && \
        umask 0077 && \
        echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa && \
        git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf https://bitbucket.org/ && \
        ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN \
        go get && \
        CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o app

# final stage of multi-stage: will appropriately *NOT* include SSH keys
FROM scratch

COPY --from=build \
        /etc/ssl /etc/ssl

COPY --from=build \
    /bld/app /app/myapp

CMD ["/app/myapp"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this already and it didn't help.
git clone can do the job, but go get throws unknown revision for all private repos
Thanks

Comment: We're using bitbucket

Comment: @kotyara85 are you positive you've pushed `v0.0.7` tag to your remote private repo? You may be able to build locally if the tag is *local* - but since Go module build will pull the code from the *remote* URL it may be missing. Verify your tags in on the bitbucket.org site and if missing - `git push --tags`.

Comment: RYes, I do have all tags pushed. 
Local build works just fine even when I delete all packages

Comment: I created a private repo in `bitbucket.og` - and used the above setup - and was able to docker build the private repo. There must be some subtle step you are missing. What does you main repo's `go.mod` file look like? No `replace` directives I hope?

Comment: Nope, I have none.
We have a on-prem bitbucket

Comment: Before `go build`, try adding the line `go env -w GOPRIVATE=bitbucket.org/<YOUR-COMPANY>`

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems to solve here:

*1. How to allow Docker to access local SSH keys, safely?*

*2. How to tell Go not to use public registry to fetch private packages?*

---

### Short Answers

1. Since **Docker v18.09**, there's a built-in solution to handle SSH authentication during the build phase ([more](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds)). It's also much easier and safer, compared to passing build arguments, and eliminates the need for a multi-stage Docker build.
2. Go has a `GOPRIVATE` environment variable to identify private packages. ([more](https://golang.org/ref/mod#private-modules))

---

### Long Answer

Step-by-step:

**1. Make sure `ssh-agent` is setup and knows the SSH key**

Github has a quick guide on this subject, explaining the process for different operating systems. See [Generating a new SSH key and adding it to SSH agent](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).

**2. Enable BuildKit for Docker**

Without **BuildKit**, `docker build` won't recognize `--ssh` option.

From the [Docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#to-enable-buildkit-builds):

> Easiest way from a fresh install of docker is to set the
> `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` environment variable when invoking the docker build
> command, such as:
>
> ```sh
> $ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .
> ```
>
> To enable docker BuildKit by
> default, set daemon configuration in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` feature
> to true and restart the daemon:
>
> ```json
> { "features": { "buildkit": true } }
> ```

Docker Desktop users can manage daemon configurations via *Preferences > Docker Engine*.

**4. Update Dockerfile**

***4.1. Make sure Git uses SSH instead of HTTPs***

Go tends to fetch public packages via `HTTPs`. You can adjust this behavior by updating `git` configurations:

```sh
RUN git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/
```

*You should probably do this on your local machine as well.*

***4.2. Request SSH access where it's required***

Each `RUN` command the needs SSH access should be mounted with `type=ssh`. For

Example:

```sh
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone ...
```

***4.3. Make sure Go knows your private packages***

Update `GOPRIVATE` variable:

```sh
RUN go env -w GOPRIVATE="github.com/your-org/private-repo"
```

*Putting all of it together, in following sample of a Dockerfile:*

```sh
FROM golang:1.16.3-alpine3.13
RUN apk update
RUN apk add git openssh
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

# You can replace github.com with any other Git host
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# Make sure git uses SSH to fetch packages, not HTTPs
RUN git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/

# Make Go knows which packages are private.
RUN go env -w GOPRIVATE="github.com/your-org/private-repo"
# GOPRIVATE is a comma separated list glob-patterns.
# You can use a wildcard to match every repo in an organization:
#   e.g.: GOPRIVATE="github.com/your-org/*"

# Mount the build command with type `ssh`.
RUN --mount=type=ssh go get && go build -o main .

CMD ["/app/main"]
```

**6. Build the image with `--ssh` option:**

Having BuildKit enabled by default:

```sh
$ docker build --ssh default -t my-app:latest .
```

Comment: Although this is the most accurate way to accomplish that, it's good to mention that `docker-compose build` [does not support](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7025) `--ssh` at the moment ;-(, so you need to build the image with `docker build` before using `docker-compose`.